# Can't wrap my mind around node.js javascript callback nest function

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I check around the web and still cant resolve this issue.

In node.js, I want to set an interval for fetching `redis` data. I just cannot make this work.

Here is my code:

```
setInterval(function(){
    redis.hget('quote','quote1', function (err, res) {
        console.log('test');
        console.log(res);
    });
}, 1000);
```

Edited:
If I use the redis snippet without setInterval, it works fine. When wrapped inside the setInterval function, it doesn't work. This redis client is from nodejs_redis. I checked err but it returns null.

Please refer to the snippet and result below

```
setInterval(function(){
   console.log(' line A');
   redis.hget('quote','quote1', function (err, res) {
      console.log('line B');
      console.log(res);
   });
}, 1000);
```

line A will log as normal. line B and res wont log no matter what.

Comment: Code looks ok. Have you checked the `err` parameter?

Comment: You may need to show the rest of your redis code that goes with this.

Comment: Thanks all for your input. At least you guys mentioned there is no problem with the code. I managed to find out the problem is with other area. It works now. Thanks guys!